# Spring websocket with rabbitmq - Adding Security at the subscription level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

In my `spring-boot` application I have `spring-security` and `spring-websocket`. Below is my websocket configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport
        implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Value( "${rabbitmq.host}" )
    private String rabbitmqHost;
    @Value( "${rabbitmq.stomp.port}" )
    private int rabbitmqStompPort;
    @Value( "${rabbitmq.username}" )
    private String rabbitmqUserName;
    @Value( "${rabbitmq.password}" )
    private String rabbitmqPassword;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker( MessageBrokerRegistry registry )
    {
        registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue").setRelayHost(rabbitmqHost).setRelayPort(rabbitmqStompPort)
                .setSystemLogin(rabbitmqUserName).setSystemPasscode(rabbitmqPassword);
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints( StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry )
    {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

And,

```
public class CustomSubProtocolWebSocketHandler extends SubProtocolWebSocketHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomSubProtocolWebSocketHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserCommons userCommons;

    CustomSubProtocolWebSocketHandler(MessageChannel clientInboundChannel,
                                      SubscribableChannel clientOutboundChannel) {
        super(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("************************************************************************************************************************New webSocket connection was established: {}", session);
        String token = session.getUri().getQuery().replace("token=", "");
        try
        {
            String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(TokenConstant.SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TokenConstant.TOKEN_PREFIX, "")).getBody().getSubject();
            Optional<UserModel> userModelOptional = userCommons.getUserByEmail(user);
            if( !userModelOptional.isPresent() )
            {
                LOGGER.error(
                        "************************************************************************************************************************Invalid token is passed with web socket request");
                throw new DataException(GeneralConstants.EXCEPTION, "Invalid user", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            LOGGER.error(GeneralConstants.ERROR, e);
        }
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.error("************************************************************************************************************************webSocket connection was closed");
        LOGGER.error("Reason for closure {} Session: {} ", closeStatus.getReason(),session.getId() );
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, closeStatus);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {

        LOGGER.error("************************************************************************************************************************Connection closed unexpectedly");
        LOGGER.error(GeneralConstants.ERROR, exception);
        super.handleTransportError(session, exception);
    }
}
```

To add the security layer while establishing connection I am accepting the token in the connection URL. So the client application will connect to `/ws?token=*****`.

But to send the message to a specific user I am constructing the subscription URL using the user_id. For example, if the logged in user id is 23, client will subscribe to `/topic/noti.23` and from the server side I am sending the message to `/topic/noti.23`.

```
 public void sendMessagesToTheDestination( WebSocketNotificationResponseBean webSocketNotificationResponseBean,
                List<String> paths )
        {
            try
            {
                for( String path : paths )
                {
                    LOGGER.info("Sending message to path: {}", path);
                    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(path, webSocketNotificationResponseBean);
                    LOGGER.info("Sent message to path: {}", path);
                }
            }
            catch( Exception e )
            {
                LOGGER.error("Error while sending web socket notification {}", e);
            }
        }
}
```

where `path` is `/topic/noti.<user_id>`.

The above implementation is working.

Now the problem is, any user with a valid token can connect to websocket and later from the browser console can subscribe manually to any URLs. For example, the user with the user_id 23, can go the browser console and add sockjs CDN and can subscribe to `/topic/noti.56` and start receiving the messages of the user with the user_id 56.

How to add the security layer here?

I tried using `convertAndSendToUser` but did not understand the session part on how the server understands the sessions and how should I subscribe from the client-side.

Thank You

Comment: I am thinking of creating a UUID string for each user and connect to the UUID

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to construct the destination dynamically. you can subscribe to a destination like '/user/queue/wishes' & still be able to send private messages.

```
String queueName = "/user/" + username  + "/queue/wishes";
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
```